# Axis issue in a D3 punchcard - need data to extend past axis limit

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a couple of issues with a my D3 punchcard (plunk is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/vIejaTBrGrV07B8UWxOb):

1. It is looking crowded, I have zooming set up but I can't figure out how to set the initial view to a more "readable" scale, with the dots more spaced out. I plan to add in tooltips and varied radii for the dots.

   ```
           //Create scale functions
       var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([1900, 2020])
                            .range([0, w]);

       var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([0, (deptlist.length)])
                            .range([h, 0]);

            //console.log(deptlist.length);

       //var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            //.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                            //.range([2, 5]);

       //Define X axis
       var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                         .scale(xScale)
                         .orient("bottom")
           .tickFormat(function(d) {
               //console.log(d);
               return d;
             });

       //Define Y axis
       var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                         .scale(yScale)
                         .orient("left")
           .tickFormat(function(d) {
               //console.log(deptlist[d]);
               return deptlist[d];
             })
           .ticks(deptlist.length - 1);
   ```
2. I can't get my deptlist[] to sort alphabetically.

It is also quite slow...

Comment: Your plunkr doesn't seem to be displaying anything...

Comment: Use `https` for the d3 script link and it should work.

Comment: Here are some ideas to make it more readable, if making it taller is not an option, you could perhaps show it in parts (ex: separating into groups, for example, Natural Sciences, Social Sciences, Arts, etc. or some other criteria). You use a smaller radius for the circles (for example: `.attr("r", 2)`) and you could start your range for the Y-axis at -1, so that the last subject appears above zero. Then you could project your axis ticks inward (and make them very light) so that it's easier to read the chart.

Comment: To sort, use: `deptlist.sort(function(x,y) { return d3.descending(x,y); });` to make it appear to be ascending, when viewed top-down. Ideally, you should use an ordinal scale (`d3.scale.ordinal()`), since your Y-axis is made of non-quantitative categories.

Comment: Your code is running slowly because you are running a `console.log` inside of a `forEach` loop of several thousand array items. Removing the `console.log` should help your speed problem.

Comment: @mutanthumb, did my response answer your question?

Comment: Yes it did, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. Better distinguish circles

You'll be better able to distinguish the dots if you make them initially smaller, and then make them bigger when the zoom level increases.

```
d3.selectAll('.dot')
  // ...
  .attr('r', 2)
```

Then when you zoom in, you can make the `r` value a product of the difference between the values in the `xScale.domain`. For example...

```
function zoomed() {

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(+d.year); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(deptlist.indexOf(d.dept)); })
        .attr('r', function(d) {
          return 120 / (xScale.domain()[1] - xScale.domain()[0]);
        });

  svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);

}
```

There are many different ways you can scale your dots, this is just one way of going about it. Your `xScale.domain()` returns the domain of your `xScale`, e.g., `[1900, 2020]`. By subtracting the first value from the second, we get a value that can be used as a reference point from which can scale the dots.

I simply took the largest possible difference, 120, and divided it by the current value of the scale (which is changed on zoom). This creates a larger value the more that the zoom is increased.

### 2. Sort Y axis alphabetically

Using some of [D3's array methods](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Arrays) you can make your code much more declarative.

Instead of doing this:

```
  var deptlist = [];

  dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    if(deptlist.indexOf(d.dept) == -1) deptlist.push(d.dept);
  });
```

You can use `d3.map`, `array.keys()`, and `d3.descending` to (a) return only `d.dept` to your array, (b) get only the unique values from the array, and (c) use the JS native [`sort` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) in combination with [`d3.ascending`](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_descending) to sort them alphabetically.

```
  var deptlistUnsorted = d3.map(dataset, function(d) {
    return d.dept;
  }).keys();

  var deptlist = deptlistUnsorted.sort(d3.descending);
```

---

As a final note, your code is running slowly because you have a `console.log` statement inside of a `forEach` loop of an array of several thousand objects. This puts a lot of strain on the browser and is generally something to avoid when dealing with arrays of that size.

I updated your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/8ghm3RFYh9zx4w90Edml?p=preview) to reflect the code above.

Comment: Yes increasing the size of circle as it zooms was just what I was looking for!  Thanks!